# The intuition behind the GlobalSpanCoefficient

Tags: python-3.x, or-tools

I am looking at the [vehicle routing problem](https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/vrp) which minimizes the cost of "the slowest truck" in a fleet.

So now the objective function should involve two quantities:

1. the sum of all transitions of all vehicles (total distance), and
2. the cost of the most expensive route

How are these values combined? I am assuming that the global span coefficient

`distance_dimension.SetGlobalSpanCostCoefficient(100)`

is involved? Is that the coefficient of a weighted sum

```
cost = w*A + (100-w)*B
```

where `A` is the cost of the slowest truck and `B` is the total distance of all trucks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it's simply: `cost = B + A`
with B = sum of all edge cost in the routes (usually set by using `routing.SetArcCostEvaluatorOfAllVehicles(arc_cost_callback)`)
and `A = w * (max{end} - min{start})`

note: `B` is needed to help solver to find a first good solution (otherwise strategy like CHEAPEST_PATH behave strangely since there is no cost on edge to choose the cheapest...), While `A` helps to "distribute" jobs by minimizing the Max cumul Var. **but** it's still not a real dispersion incentive
e.g. supposing a dimension with `cumul_start = 0` and 4 routes with cost 0,0,6,6 it is as good as 2,2,2,6 (or 6,6,6,6 but `B` is higher here).
i.e. `max(cumul_end) == 6` in both cases.

I added a section on GlobalSpan [here](https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/vrp#global_span) in the doc.

ps: take a look at https://github.com/google/or-tools/issues/685#issuecomment-388503464
pps: in the doc example try to change `maximum_distance = 3000` by 1800 or 3500 if I remember well ;)
ppps: Note than you can have several GlobalSpan on several dimensions and objective is just the sum of all this costs multiply by their respective coefficient...

Comment: any ideas on the magnitude of `w`? Also, the solver might try to increase `min{start}` to decrease the contribution of `A` to the objective function, if `fix_start_cumul_to_zero=False`, is that right?

Comment: I think it's possible provided that this increase doesn't increase the max{end} as well. Also you could have B cost impacted which could prevent that.

Comment: magnitude? sorry don't get it. All costs are stored as int64 if I recall well and w is just the scalar you apply to your dimension e.g. B in km and you have 4 vehicles doing 1,2,3,4 km respectively, so B will be `10`. Now suppose A cost is in **second** all vehicle start at 0 and the max route take 30min A will be `w * 1800` (if you store your value in seconds). Unfortunately w is a int so you can't "divide" (i.e. multiply by 0.something etc)

Comment: i was wondering if there are any thoughts on why to choose `w=100` instead of `w=10` or `w=10000` but i guess its just trial and error

Comment: Just for example purpose using 1000 i just "shift" digit of SpanCost from route cost so I can see/check both value in the blink of an eye. Otherwise you need to answer the question what is the cost to increase this value by 1 unit against other cost value and set coefficient accordingly -> i.e. start to have a trade off between constraints (e.g. should I increase my route by w*N km or use an other vehicle with a fixed cost of M)...